# Battery management systems (BMS) that allow shorts

Tags: lithium-ion, short-circuit, bms

I'm in a quandary.

I'm a DIY guy building a magic prop that powers a 12 Vdc 8 ohm bulb, using three, high-drain, 14650 Li-ion cells and an arduino, controlling a MOSFET. I'm powering the bulb from the BMS's P+ and P- terminals, but the 8 ohm connection is seen as a short, so it “correctly” disconnects the pack, which for me it's paradoxically not a short, and right there is me being stuck in my quandary which I can't figure out how to overcome.

Are there BMSs that are designed to allow near-shorts? I'm not even sure how to ask the question. Googling gets convoluted as well when looking for BMS design capabilities offered and desired. Thanks.

Comment: Please add a link to those "high-drain, 14650 Li-ion cells", so we can see if they are rated to power a 12 Vdc 8 ohm bulb.

Comment: Please add a link to your 12 Vdc 8 ohm bulb so we can see if it is incandescent, LED, or something else.

Comment: Misconfigured BMS.  Get a BMS correctly configured for that pack.   Or a pack correct for a BMS that allows 8 ohms.

Comment: I measured the 12v bulb current at 1.5A. 

2 pc AWT IMR 14650 BATTERY 3.7v 1100mAh 8a HIGH DRAIN FLAT TOP, its link is here: 

https://www.ebay.com/itm/372864816411

The 12v bulb is a 50w Philips RV & Marine 12vdc bulb. I measured its resistance using a DMM and on a 200 ohm range got a "00.8" displayed for its resistance.

Answer (score 2):

> Are there BMSs that are designed to allow near-shorts?

1. The point of a BMS is to protect cells
2. A "near short" (as you call it) damages cells that are too small or have too high a resistance to power that load
3. Hence, a BMS shuts down in case of a "near short" to protect those cells

> how to overcome.

Either the BMS is appropriate for those cells, which are not rated for a high enough current to power your load. If so, get a Li-ion battery with larger cells that can supply the "near short" current. It will have a BMS that is configured for a higher current, so it will not shut down.

Or, your lamp is incandescent and its cold resistance is much lower than 8 Ohm. If so, replace the lamp with an LED lamp (lower power for a given luminosity, no inrush current). If that is not possible, place an [Inrush Current Limiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inrush_current_limiter) in series with the lamp.

Or, the cells *are* rated for a high enough current but the BMS is a poor match for them. If so, replace a BMS with one rated for higher current.

Comment: Yeah, an incandescent will do it for sure. But OP can grab an ohmmeter and measure the resistance of a cold bulb.